# Add a ranking field and return top 3 data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you please help me get the answer in sql? I want to make my current table return a "Rank" field that shows top 3 product based on the "Sell Count" each day.

My Table

```
Date    Name    ProductName SellCount
1/2/2014    John    Product1    55
1/2/2014    John    Product4    55
1/2/2014    John    Product7    10
1/2/2014    John    Product10   100
1/3/2014    John    Product2    55
1/3/2014    John    Product5    77
1/3/2014    John    Product8    25
1/3/2014    John    Product11   50
1/4/2014    John    Product3    55
1/4/2014    John    Product6    5
1/4/2014    John    Product9    44
1/4/2014    John    Product12   660
```

I want it to Return the "Rank" field. So I can see the top 3 product sold for each day. Also, if there are two sell count number equal to each other (example on "rank" field date "1/2/2014"): I want it to auto assign one of the rank as 2 and the other as 3.

```
Date    Name    ProductName  SellCount  Rank
1/2/2014    John    Product1    55  3
1/2/2014    John    Product4    55  2
1/2/2014    John    Product10   100 1
1/3/2014    John    Product11   50  3
1/3/2014    John    Product2    55  2
1/3/2014    John    Product5    77  1
1/4/2014    John    Product9    44  3
1/4/2014    John    Product3    55  2
1/4/2014    John    Product12   660 1
```

I hope my questions are clear enough. If you guys need me to elaborate please let me know. I would appreciate the solution in SQL format. Thanks All!

Part 2 Question:
Guys What if I add another Column call group

my new table is

```
       Date Name    Group          ProductName  SellCount
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product7    10
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product10   100
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1B  Product2    55
1/2/2014    John    Group1A         Product1    55
1/3/2014    John    Group1B         Product6    5
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product9    44
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product4    55
1/3/2014    John    LargeGroup1A    Product5    77
1/4/2014    John    LargeGroup2A    Product8    25
1/5/2014    John    LargeGroup2B    Product12   660
1/6/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product11   50
1/7/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product3    55
```

(I added a new column called group, I want it to return the ranking and have it based on the "Date", "Group", "Sell Count" so it can give ranking for top 3. For example on 1/2/2014 John in "BIGGroup1A" sold  100 and 10. So the Rank will be 1 in product 10 and rank 2 in product 7. On the same day 1/2/2014, he sold 55 and 55 in two different groups so they both should be 1. I filled the rest of the ranking to match the logic im going after.

```
Date    Name    Group          ProductName  SellCount   Rank
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product7    10           2
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1A  Product10   100          1
1/2/2014    John    BigGroup1B  Product2    55           1
1/2/2014    John    Group1A         Product1    55           1
1/3/2014    John    Group1B         Product6    5            1
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product9    44           2
1/3/2014    John    Group1C         Product4    55           1
1/3/2014    John    LargeGroup1A    Product5    77           1
1/4/2014    John    LargeGroup2A    Product8    25           1
1/5/2014    John    LargeGroup2B    Product12   660          1
1/6/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product11   50           2
1/7/2014    John    MediumGroup2A   Product3    55           1
```

Thanks Again!For helping me find the solution for the second part.

Comment: I added part 2 for the questions. Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Windowing Functions together with CTE for this type of problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    [Date]      DATE,
    Name        VARCHAR(20),
    ProductName VARCHAR(20),
    SellCount   INT
)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
('1/2/2014', 'John', 'Product1', 55), ('1/2/2014', 'John', 'Product4', 55), ('1/2/2014', 'John', 'Product7', 10),
('1/2/2014', 'John', 'Product10', 100), ('1/3/2014', 'John', 'Product2', 55), ('1/3/2014', 'John', 'Product5', 77),
('1/3/2014', 'John', 'Product8', 25), ('1/3/2014', 'John', 'Product11', 50), ('1/4/2014', 'John', 'Product3', 55),
('1/4/2014', 'John', 'Product6', 5), ('1/4/2014', 'John', 'Product9', 44), ('1/4/2014', 'John', 'Product12', 660);

--Start of the solution
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, [Date] ORDER BY SellCount DESC)
    FROM #Temp --Replace this with your Table
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE [Rank] <= 3
ORDER BY [Date], [Rank] DESC
--End of the solution    

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

**RESULT**

```
Date       Name                 ProductName          SellCount   Rank
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------
2014-01-02 John                 Product4             55          3
2014-01-02 John                 Product1             55          2
2014-01-02 John                 Product10            100         1
2014-01-03 John                 Product11            50          3
2014-01-03 John                 Product2             55          2
2014-01-03 John                 Product5             77          1
2014-01-04 John                 Product9             44          3
2014-01-04 John                 Product3             55          2
2014-01-04 John                 Product12            660         1
```

Comment: Hi Wewsthmeance, I'm new to SQL; the table is already created and its called "MyTable", can you provide me the SQL so I can put it in sql server studio to test if the ranking field works. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I just created some sample data for you. Just replace the `#Temp` inside the CTE with `MyTable`. See updated answer with comments.

Comment: Can you help me solve the part 2 problem when you have the time?Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these windowing functions in Sql Server I am sure one will fit your needs.

[DENSE_RANK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825(v=sql.110).aspx) - Returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result set, without any gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row is one plus the number of distinct ranks that come before the row in question.

[RANK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102(v=sql.110).aspx) - Returns the rank of each row within the partition of a result set. The rank of a row is one plus the number of ranks that come before the row in question.

[ROW_NUMBER](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.110).aspx) - Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

[Other Sql Server Ranking Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.110).aspx)